# copy paste in virtualbox ("guest additions" not available)

Tags: virtualbox

How can I copy/paste with virtualbox ?

Some talks about "gest additions", but there's no "guest additions" on my "Machine" menu.

So what can I do ?

I selected "Bidirectional" in my vb options-general-advanced-Shared clipboard

But how to copy/paste then

EDIT : sorry for this, but see my answer, I'm sure it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to copy/paste in my virtual box because my box was a command line, not a user interface.

As Vasily Alexeev pointed out to me, Guest Additions, which allows for copy/poste, only works with user interface.

Answer (score 2):

You should install "Guest Additions" into your guest operating system. You should select "Devices - Insert guest additions CD image". This will insert a virtual CD containing the additions into the virtual CD drive of your guest OS. After that you should be able to install them (the exact steps for installation vary between different guest OSes).

Comment: It's one of the menus of your VM window.

Comment: I did "Insert guest additions CD image". Then I need to install ? But how ?

Comment: Which OS did you install into your VM?

Comment: hashicorp/preceise32  (ubuntu 12)

Comment: open a terminal window and run `sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85132/discussion-between-vasily-alexeev-and-trogne).

Comment: Terminal window ?  Am I not already in a terminal window (devices menu etc) ?

Comment: please go to the chat using the link I posted in my previous comment

Comment: Answered in the chat. See my answer below.